# Two IP addresses, different network ID = different networks?

Tags: ip, traceroute, whois

Part of my coursework involves tracerouting a number of UK academic websites. When tracing oxford.ac.uk, before reaching the end (129.67.242.154), it goes through a few  192.76.xx.xx routers which (after some whoising) i determined are oxford university network IP addresses. Does this mean that the website is being hosted on a different network (Since the network IDs are different). Or, does it use a different IP address AND exist in the same network (if thats possible)

```
 9     6 ms     6 ms     5 ms  ctestb.backbone.ox.ac.uk [192.76.21.9]
 10     6 ms     5 ms     5 ms  bmusb.backbone.ox.ac.uk [192.76.22.201]
 11     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  bmus-lompi1.sdc.ox.ac.uk [192.76.32.66]
 12     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  aurochs-web-154.nsms.ox.ac.uk [129.67.242.154]
```

Comment: networks are not defined by hostnames, they are defined by subnet masks. When you run a traceroute, you see the gateways that are hit while traversing networks from one point to another. A host may have multiple IPs, both on the same and/or on different networks. A host also may have multiple DNS hostnames pointing at a single IP that it has, or multiple DNS hostnames, each pointing to a different IP it has, whether on the same network or on a different network. It may help to see the traceroute output with specific questions about any given lines on it - as it is, your question isn't clear.

Comment: It may not be defined by the hostname, but when the network IDs are the same for hops 9, 10, 11, there is a clear link between a network and a hostname. What i am asking is, why does the end server (hop 12) use 129.67 when the others use 192.76

Comment: Why would it need to use the same prefix? The whole point of routers is to enable connectivity between different networks. I don’t quite get your question as a whole. Also, without the subnet mask, you cannot even know whether any of these machines is on a different network.

Comment: The network IDs are not the same for hops 9, 10, and 11. The RDNS name can be entirely arbitrary.

Comment: is the network ID the first 3 decimals of the IP address?

Comment: @WillDonaghy There is no fixed network ID (more commonly called the network address or the prefix) with modern CIDR routing. Fixed-length network IDs only existed with classful networking two decades ago. With CIDR routing the network prefix length can be any size from 0 to 32 in IPv4. Also, they aren't "decimals" -- each three-digit part of an IPv4 address is an octet.

Comment: Can  someone please just either admit they don't know the answer, or tell me why www.oxford.ac.uk uses 129 when all their other hops show 192.

Comment: Of course we don’t know the answer. We can’t. Neither can you. That’s just how it is. If you want to know, you’ll have to contact Oxford IT.

Comment: https://help.it.ox.ac.uk/network/addresses/index

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Nice find. You should add that as the answer ;)

Comment: They are two different networks both owned by Oxford University. From `whois`: inetnum:        129.67.0.0 - 129.67.255.255
netname:        OXFORDNET
descr:          Oxford University

inetnum:        192.76.32.0 - 192.76.32.255
netname:        OXNET-26
descr:          Oxford University Computing Services

Comment: From the link above "The IP address ranges allocated to the university consist primarily of two main networks, namely 163.1.0.0/16 and 129.67.0.0/16 (historically, these were "class B" networks). Additionally the university has been assigned several /24 networks starting 192.76 (originally "class C" networks). These are used by IT Services for special purposes, and by one or two departments for historical reasons."

Answer (score 1):

Each line is a different network.

The traceroute command print one line per hop while don't reach the searched ip.

The itermediary lines is routers of other networks between your pc and the destination.

Your local network its probaly 192.76.21.0/24 (192.176.21.1 - 192.176.21.254) and this network have a neighbor network (probaly 192.76.22.0/24) and this second have other neighbor (192.76.32.0/24) and this reach the destiny IP 129.67.242.154

Sorry for my bad english, i'm a new ESL student, but old ICT professional.

Comment: Please note that the snippet starts at hop 9.

Comment: ALL four of those IP addresses can be whois'd back to oxford university. My question is why does the last one use a 129 and others 192. The same thing happens when you traceroute leeds.ac.uk

Comment: @WillDonaghy: Perhaps you should go back to earlier coursework that covers what I.P. addresses are and how they're used.

Comment: this is the first coursework

Comment: And the statement "each line is a different network" simply isn't true

Comment: @WillDonaghy So do tell, why wouldn’t it be true? It’s entirely possible and plausible. Of course, “each line’s host resides in a different network” is a more appropriate description.

Comment: Okay so obviously the 192 IPs are "neighbors" that all exist under the larger "oxford university network umbrella" but my question is what does it tell us that the destination IP is 129

Comment: @WillDonaghy: The destination IP is 129 tells us the destination IP is 129.

Comment: @WillDonaghy They are two different networks both owned by Oxford University. From `whois`: inetnum:        129.67.0.0 - 129.67.255.255
netname:        OXFORDNET
descr:          Oxford University

inetnum:        192.76.32.0 - 192.76.32.255
netname:        OXNET-26
descr:          Oxford University Computing Services